# Chrome DevTools Protocol version 1.2

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find and understand the Chrome DevTools Protocol version 1.2.

The following page lists the HTTP endpoints for protocol version 1.3: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#endpoints. I looked through the commit history for the repository and found a link to https://github.com/buggerjs/bugger-daemon/blob/master/README.md#api, which "roughly" shows versions 1.1.

Where can I learn more information about version 1.2's HTTP endpoints? This is the current implementation as 1.3 is a RC. Thank you!

Google search is not helpful since it removes punctuation: `chrome devtools protocol "Protocol-Version" "1.2"`.

Comment: The site says 1.2 was released in Chrome 54, so here's the source code for that version: [link](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/54.0.2840.99:chrome/browser/devtools/device/devtools_android_bridge.cc;l=61).